# Strict Mocks using AAA syntax of Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Is it possible to create a "strict" mock using the new AAA syntax of Rhino Mocks? The issue I am seeing is that the library I am mocking often returns null as a valid return value (which I handle in my function), so using the default mock I can never be sure if I tested all paths or I forgot to set some expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Rhino Mocks 3.6 we finally have: `MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<T>()`. GenerateMock does not create strict mocks.

Answer (score 1):

`MockRepository.GenerateMock<T>()` should return a 'strict' mock - as opposed to `MockRepository.GenerateStub<T>()`, but couldn't you just define an explicit method setup that returns null?

Comment: I can see only MockRepository.GenerateMock<T>(), but it doesn't work - unexpected calls still just return null.

Comment: It just adds to the pain, because I have to debug the test every time I forget to setup the method to figure out which one was it.

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered the name. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the new syntax

MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock; 
MockRepository.GenerateMock;

Answer (score 0):

They functionality has changed and GenerateMock() doesn't return a strict mock.
StrictMock is still available for use. Just not under the new syntax.

Ayende talks [more about how CreateMock is deprecated, replaced by StrictMock here](http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#CreateMockisdeprecated,replacedbyStrictMockTheuseofStrictMockisdiscouraged).

Note:
Added new answer so people can easily find Ayende thoughts on the change.

Answer (score 0):

MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock; generates a strick mock.
MockRepository.GenerateMock; generates a Dynamic Mock.